# Creating an Excel workbook with Apache POI with content type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, content-type

When I create a simple Excel workbook file with the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) 3.17 Java library, it produces a file with content type **application/octet-stream**

(checked by running command

```
file --mime-type -b test.xlsx
```

on a Mac).

Code to create XLSX file:

```
package apachepoitest;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");

        Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("test");

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
        
        workbook.close();
    }

}
```

However, when I create a content-wise identical XSLX file with Excel, the content type is     **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**.

Is it possible to force Apache POI to save the XLSX file with content type **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet**, and if yes, how?

**Edit:** I have also verified the file [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) (which determines the content type) using a hex editor. The first 8 bytes of the file identified as **application/octet-stream** (created by Apache POI) are

50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 08

According to https://www.filesignatures.net/ these 8 bytes are no magic number matching a file type, but the first 4 bytes, i.e. 50 4B 03 04 match [several file types](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=50%204B%2003%2004&mode=SIG).

The first 8 bytes of the file identified as  **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** (created by Excel) are

50 4B 03 04 14 00 06 00

, which is the [magic number for XLSX, PPTX and DOCS according to filesignatures.net](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=50%204B%2003%2004%2014%2000%2006%2000&mode=SIG).

Comment: Try checking the mime type with Apache Tika? Could be a bug in your version of the file tool

Comment: Both files are working XLSX files, so that's not the problem. I tried Apache Tika, and it gives the content type as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" for both files, probably through some intelligent analysis. But my problem is rather that the magic number in the file (first bytes) differs in the file created by Apache POI from the "real" Excel file. This causes other problems, which I won't go into now to keep the discussion in track.

Comment: "...the magic number in the file (first bytes) differs in the file created by Apache POI from the "real" Excel file..."  That's not true. Have you checked this? For me `XSSFWorkbook ` files created using `apache poi` also start with `50 4B 03 04` since they are ZIP archives as `*.xlsx` files created from `Excel` are too.

Comment: Does `Mac` also have `mimetype` command? For me (`Linux`) `file --mime-type` also fails but `mimetype -a` returns exactly the same for all `*.xlsx` files.

Comment: Are you aware that a great many file types don't have magic numbers, and many more don't have unique ones? OOXML files (like xlsx) just have the zip magic number, you have to check the `[Content_Types].xml` file within to know the overall type

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, the first 4 bytes do not differ. But the magic number can be either 4 or 8 bytes, and there is an ambiguity, as the 4 first bytes are common for many files. In Mac there is not a built-in mimetype command. And nevertheless, the problem is not what a specific command outputs.

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, I'm aware of the ambiguity. Nevertheless, I think ideally Apache POI should produce files as close to possible to Excel (or other way around, I don't want to start a political argument here). Thanks for the tip with [Content_Types].xml.

Comment: @simon It would be lovely if file types had a 4 or 8 byte magic, most don't... Try https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L4702 for "real world", or even https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L5189 for a fairly well thought-through format!